# MobileFirst Windows Notification Services

Tags: windows, ibm-mobilefirst, push

In order to manage Push Notifications for Windows Phone hybrid apps, it seems that Microsoft Notification Service is the only one supported by MobileFirst 7.1. I wanted Windows Notification Services but the support seems not present. Could anybody confirm it to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@giuseppe You are probably trying Silverlight Hybrid. Silverlight Hybrid does not support WNS. If you want to use WNS - use the Windows 8 Hybrid (not Windows Phone 8 Hybrid)

Comment: My app is a WINJS APPX supporting Windows Phone 8.1 and I hope this one would support WNS. But it's not a Silverlight app.

Comment: Yes it will support. That platform is called Windows8 in MobileFirst - and works on Windows 8.1 phones (I know the nomenclature is a bit confusing)

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, MPNS is supported in **Windows Phone 8** apps, while WNS is supported for **Windows 8.1** apps. These are two different environments.

See here in the Developer Center:

- Windows Phone 8: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/#setupWP8
- Windows 8: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/#setupWin8

And here in the Knowledge Center:

- Windows Phone 8: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_WP8.html
- Windows 8: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_win8.html